# How to check which URL is loaded and include a page based on this?

Tags: php, html, url, ssi

```
<?php 
if(...) {
 include("home.php");
} else if(...) {
 include("about.php"); 
}
?>
```

If i click on the home button it will include the home.php page and if i click on the about button it will include the about.php on page load. I want to have it this way so that i can have one index.php file and not multiple ones for each page.

Is there a way to check the url that is being loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also use a $_GET and a switch statement. first check to see if the get var is set, and if it is use the switch statement, else, use the default.

something like

```
<?php 
   if(isset($_GET['page'])) { 
$page = $_GET['page'];
 // roll GET into a var so you can do some error checking if you wish, // 
 // clean it up if need be //
    switch($page) {
        case 'about':
            include('about.php');
            break;
        case 'home':
            include('contact.php');
            break;
        default:
            include('home.php');
            break;
      } 
} else {
  include('home.php');
}
?>
```

This way, you are double covered. If get isn't set, it automatically includes home.php, but if it is set, you have several predefined options to choose from. if someone is messing with the url, home.php will be included anyway.

[PHP switch statement](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php)

Answer (score 4):

```
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']
```

http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.server.php

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to investigate mod_rewrite.